# Implementing a simple scheduling algorithm within Excel

Tags: excel, algorithm, date

I have an Excel spreadsheet that stores a set of flashcards that I would like to study.
Each flashcard has one front field and one back field, represented in the Excel sheet as a front field and back field respectively.

I recently learned about spaced repetition and would like to implement the SuperMemo 2 algorithm, described [here](https://github.com/thyagoluciano/sm2). What this does in essence is tell me when to next review a flashcard for optimum recall of that fact, based on the grade I give it each time I review it (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition)).

This would require adding 4 new columns to each row (each flashcard), resulting in a sheet that looks like this:

```
1: Front
2: Back
3: Grade
4: Repetitions
5: EaseFactor
6: Interval
7: NextReview
```

Each day I would have to sort by NextReview (which would hold the date), question myself on each flashcard where NextReview is a date earlier than or equal to the current date. Then I would enter a grade between 0 and 5 (as described by the linked article) and based on this input, Repetitions, EaseFactor, Interval and NextReview would change accordingly.

I can't seem to get a functioning version of the algorithm working, it would require that every time Grade is modified and the Grade >= 3, Repetitions increments, Ease is modified, Interval is modified and NextReview is equal to the current date with Interval days added to it. This is not a complete description of the algorithm, see my note and the article linked above.

The excel sheet would also need default values inserted into Repetitions, EaseFactor, Interval and NextReview's place: Repetitions at 0, EaseFactor at 2.5, Interval at 0 and NextReview to the earliest possible Date.

The problem I'm having at the minute is with the way the algorithm is written:

```
new interval = old interval * new ease
```

This is problematic because it would require a cell to modify itself based on its current value, which to the best of my knowledge is not allowed.
How would I overcome this?

For default values, I've used:

```
=IF(<cell>="", <default value>, <cell>)
```

And I can use simple arithmetic in cells to automatically update NextReview based on the current date and Interval.

NOTE: NextReview is not mentioned in the article but it is required for practical real world applications of the algorithm. After each review that is correct, it is updated to equal the current date + new interval. If a review is incorrect it is set to its NULL value.

Comment: "*cell to modify itself based on its current value*" You can use a VBA macro.

Comment: Agree. VBA or Power Query can handle that.  I would go with Power Query, pretty easy to learn and use in excel.

Comment: This really sounds like study procrastination :D Bu anyway, you may need to create another sheet containing all of your permanently saved "variables"